# Use Neo4jGraph.open() or GraphFactory.open() to access remote Neo4j database in Java

Tags: java, neo4j, tinkerpop

I'm using the Tinkerpop's `GraphFactory.open(Configuration configuration)` Java command to access a Neo4j database.

A working minimum example is:

```
Configuration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
configuration.addProperty("gremlin.graph", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph");
configuration.addProperty("gremlin.neo4j.directory", "tmp/neo4j");
GraphFactory.open(configuration);
```

However, I want to connect to a remote Neo4j database instead.
So I need something like

```
configuration.addProperty("gremlin.neo4j.directory", "ip:port");
```

which results in an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory path [C:\Users\backend\192.168.56.102:7474] for Neo4j store.
```

Seems like Neo4j tries to access the ip:port like a file path...
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, that approach won't work. `Neo4jGraph` is designed to work as embedded and thus requires either a file system location for the database files or it can become a node in a HA cluster which is described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration).

Your other choice is to use a third-party implementation that uses the Bolt protocol, [neo4j-gremlin-bolt](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt). That should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you!

 I'll try using the `neo4j-gremlin-bolt` implementation because Bolt is enabled in Neo4j by default starting from version 3.0 (Source [The binary Bolt Protocol](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) )

Comment: @stephen mallette Add on question: what is a use case for embedded Neo4jGraph when only one process can work on the graph at a time, and open can only be called once? unit tests?

Comment: Not every application requires tons of servers I suppose. I've used it at times for graphs i was doing analysis on that fit in memory but I wanted easily persisted for future use.

Comment: SteelBridgeLabs GitHub has been removed, so this answer is now useless... For cases such as this, please, please, _please_, always provide sample code in the answer instead of relying on external resources.

Comment: SteelBridgeLabs was a link to a code repository/library. A code sample from there would not have been terribly useful if the library no longer exists. It looks like some forks are still available if you search github. This one looks most recent: https://github.com/Tanemahuta/neo4j-gremlin-bolt

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to stephen mallette, I found a solution.

From Neo4j 3.0, the Bolt protocol is enabled by default.

So I used [neo4j-gremlin-bolt](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt) to connect to my Neo4j remote database via Java as follows:

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://<IP>", AuthTokens.basic("user", "pass"));
Graph graph = new Neo4JGraph(driver, vertexIdProvider, edgeIdProvider));
```

Read about the ID providers at the link provided.